# The injective hull of the ring of all eventually constant sequences of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: modules, injective-module

Let $R$ be the ring of all eventually constant sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. It's known that the injective hull $E(R_R)$ of $R_R$ is $S:=\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_2$. I need to check this myself. I know that $S_S$ is injective. But how can I prove that $S_R$ (i.e., $S$ as a right $R$-module) is injective ?!.

Comment: It's a result in Lam's book: **Lectures on Modules and Rings**. It asserts that if $R_i$ are right (left) self-injective rings then $\prod_{i\in I} R_i$ is a right (left) self-injective ring and vice versa. In particular, if $R_i$ is a field then $\prod_{i\in I} R_i$ is both right and left self-injective ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show each $\mathbb Z_2$ is an injective $R$ module, since arbitrary products of injective modules are injective.

$R$ is commutative von Neumann regular (actually it is even a boolean ring) so its simple modules are injective.  (Rings whose simple modules are injective are called V rings and their equivalence in commutative rings with VNR rings is not hard.)

Finally then, each factor of $\mathbb Z_2$ is given an $R$ module structure with the given module action (which is suggested to be coordinatewise). Concretely, each one looks like $e_iS$ where $e_i\in R$ is the element with $1$ on the $i$th index and zero elsewhere.  These simple modules are mutually nonisomorphic, since they have distinct annihilators in $R$.  But all of them only have two elements, so they can only be simple.

Comment: How is the right $R$-action on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is given?. Notice that we need this action to be compatible with the ring structure of $S$, i.e., if $(t_n)\in S$ and $(x_n)\in R$ then the action $(t_n)(x_n)$ must coincide with the product of these two elements as elements of the ring $S$. Am I correct?

Comment: Updated the answer with a few more details.

Comment: May you please give me an explicit answer of my question? I just ask what is the $R$-action that can be given to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ so that the action is compatible with the ring structure of $S$?. I know already that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is simple under any module structure.

Comment: If $S=\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}R_\lambda$ is a direct product of rings with unities, then, indeed, $S$ is a right $S$-module. However, each $R_k$ ($k\in \Lambda$) can be given a right $S$-module structure by defining $a\lbrace r_\lambda \rbrace_{\lambda\in\Lambda}=ar_k$ for every $a\in R_k$ and $\lbrace r_\lambda \rbrace_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\in S$.

Comment: Recall that if $\mathscr{L}:=\lbrace M_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ is a collection of right $R$-modules, then the product $\prod_{i\in I}M_i$ is a right $R$-module with an $R$-action given by $\lbrace x_i\rbrace r=\lbrace x_i r\rbrace_{i\in I}$ for every $\lbrace x_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ and $r\in R$. Regarding $S$ as a product of $S$-modules and acting by an element $\lbrace t_\lambda \rbrace$ on an element $\lbrace y_\lambda \rbrace$ from the right, one gets $\lbrace y_\lambda \rbrace \lbrace t_\lambda \rbrace = \lbrace y_\lambda \lbrace t_\lambda \rbrace \rbrace= \lbrace y_\lambda t_\lambda \rbrace$

Comment: which coincides with the product of $\lbrace y_\lambda \rbrace, \lbrace t_\lambda \rbrace$ as two elements of the ring $S$. Hence, the $S$-module structure on each $R_k$ ($k\in \Lambda$) makes the $S$-action on $S$ when regarded as a direct product of a family of right $S$-modules compatible with the usual $S$-action on $S$ (which is given by the usual product of elements of the ring $S$).

Comment: Excuse me, I divided my comment into three parts because it's too long. I hope I clarified my point of view.

Comment: @HusseinEid $e_i$ is an element of $R$. $e_iS$ is a submodule of $S$ (only because the ring is all commutative.)  Do you not agree that this map $s\mapsto e_is$ is a module surjection onto the $i$th position of $S$?  I should think this makes the module action abundantly clear.  The action of an element of $R$ on the $i$th-position is just the $i$th coefficient of the element from $R$ multiplying things in the submodule.

Comment: I think the $R$-action you gave to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coincides with the $R$-action I gave to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in the comments above, doesn't it?. However, I gave $\mathbb{Z}_2$ an $R$-action directly without identifying it with $e_iS$. In the above comments I showed that the right $R$-action of $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in R$ on an element $a \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ of the $k$th position can't be defined as anything but $a x_k$. Is this what you meant ?!.  Let me know if I'm mistaken. 

Thanks anyway.

Comment: @HusseinEid I think they describe the same thing.